# Can't pass string variable to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown and when one of the items is clicked, I call this function:

```
  onClick(type) {
    type.preventDefault();
    let query = type.target.text;
    PokeApi.pokemonType(query).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

The console.log returns undefined.

When I do this:

```
  onClick(type) {
    type.preventDefault();
    let query = type.target.text;
    console.log(query);
    console.log(typeof query);
    PokeApi.pokemonType(query).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

The first console.log will return the text of the dropdown item. The second console.log will return string. Now, when I pass query to PokeApi.pokemonType, I can get back a 404 error from the api and the third console.log returns undefined.

But if I pass in the text of the dropdown directly like this:

```
  onClick(type) {
    type.preventDefault();
    PokeApi.pokemonType("ice").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Everything works perfectly fine and I get the correct object back from the api.

Any idea why this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the network panel and look at the request. Look to see what is being sent when you hard code it versus when you use .text

Comment: Try to use `onChange` instead, and to get the selected value you can use: `query = type.target.value`!

Comment: Okay, so hard coded, the request url is http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/ice and with query its http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/%20ice%20/

Comment: So where is %20 coming from?

Comment: So you have whitespace in your text. :) TADA, trim it.

Comment: Oh wow so this is where it was coming from: <a href="#"> {type} </a>

Comment: I assumed it would be removed :S. Thanks for your help epascarello!

Comment: `>SPACE{type}SPACE <`

Comment: You would be better off using data attributes, than the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value of the dropdown selected element

```
var sel = document.getElementById('myDropdown'),
var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: I think `self.value` will do the job !!